# How to create a new table view in XCode 4.3.2?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4.3

May sound like a stupid question, but I simply can't find the function of adding subclasses in XCode 4.3.2 anymore. I am sure, in the previous release of XCode I could choose the subclass of the view, before actually pressing the Create button in the dialog.
I was not using the storyboard, when I initially created my project. Is this the issue? 
Thanks, René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File` > `New` > `Files` > `Cocoa Touch` > `Objective-C class` > `Next` > `Subclass of ...`

Comment: yep, just found it myself ;-) a bit hidden though... anyway, thanks and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the answer myself: File / New File / Cocoa Touch, Objective-C Class, Subclass of UITableViewController and set Option With XIB for user interface.